# Why does it give the " 'int' object is not callable" with my custom class

Tags: python, function, class, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am making this very simple genetic algorithm in python. I made a custom class which is going to be the "creatures" evolving. I made instances of the class, and when I tried to call a function of the class from one of the objects it gave me the "'int' object is not callable" error.

Here is all my code:

```
import random as random

class Creature:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2, value3, generation, index):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.generation = generation
        self.index = index

    def generation(self):
        test = self.value1 * self.value2 - self.value3
        if test >= 50:
            newGeneration.append(self)
            self.index = len(newGeneration)


creatures = []
newGeneration = []
for i in range(100):
    value1 = random.randint(5,10)
    value2 = random.randint(5,30)
    value3 = random.randint(30,50)
    creatures.append(Creature(value1, value2, value3, 1, i))


for i in range(len(creatures) - 1):
    creatures[i].generation()


for i in newGeneration:
    print(i.value1 * i.value2 - i.value3)
```

when run, it gives me this:

```
    line 29, in <module>
    creatures[i].generation()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `generation` attribute, is an `int` you can't call it

Comment: You have `self.generation` both as attribute and method. Change one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to call the method `generation` but it's hidden with the attribut `generation` whici is an int.

I'd call the method `generate`

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2, value3, generation, index):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.generation = generation
        self.index = index

    def generate(self):
        test = self.value1 * self.value2 - self.value3
        if test >= 50:
            newGeneration.append(self)
            self.index = len(newGeneration)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try taking out the `-1`, the range function already takes the first number down to `0`; so it gives you the error because you are trying to call `creatures[-1]`, although I thought that had to work.